# Grouping variable must be a vector or a character array

Tags: matlab

I have done the following:

```
I=imread('image.png');
I2=im2double(I);
cidx = fcm(I2,5);
```

When I tried running the following command:

```
 silhouette(I2,cidx)
```

I got the following error:

```
Error using grp2idx (line 39)
Grouping variable must be a vector or a character array.

Error in silhouette (line 79)
[idx,cnames] = grp2idx(clust);
```

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

With problems like this, you want to work backwards through the errors. It states

> > Grouping variable must be a vector or a character array.

and obviously it is the variable `clust` that it is complaining about. So look at the file `silhouette`, and figure out what the variable `clust` is set to. I am imagining it is not a vector…

When you turn on the debugger to stop on error, you will be "in the function" where the error occurs and then you can examine the variables, move up and down the stack, and figure out exactly what went wrong.

If you still need more help, let us know what you got when you typed

```
whos clust
```

in the context of `silhouette`.